# <icon> tag not working in IE8 twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hover, twitter-bootstrap

So the + symbol should show the form and then be removed, while the - symbol will do a call to remove the user. I have edited out the portion where it shows the list of guests.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZjM8/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I'm using `<icon>`. This works fine, however in IE 8 you must use `<i>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `<icon>` tag with `<span>`

http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/bG4hv/3/

On a side note, in IE8 you get this error in the console. You might want to also dig into that.

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getStyle' 
LayoutCM.js, line 195 character 5
```

Comment: The problem with this one is the icons are not hover activated. ie.. don't show them unless I hover. Also, the - icon should be shown at the same time. The - icon isn't supposed to do anything.

Comment: essentially run it in chrome and then attempt to duplicate the functionality in IE8

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to IE8 not showing the icons. - Replace the icon tags with "+" and "-" and it works.